# Post redirected to page with same name but DIFFERENT permalink

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I have a page **named** `park&read` and a post **named** `park&read`.

WP removes the &, so the post and the page share the **slug**  `parkread`.

Since the page has a parent-page, its permalink is `/servizi/parkread/`

Since the permalink structure of my posts is 
`/news/%postname%/`, the permalink of the post is `/news/parkread/`

The **issue** is that when trying to view the post's detail, WP redirects me to the page.

I don't get why two different permalinks lead to such a conflict.
Is this normal behavior?

Could the cause be that I don't have a category_base set in my permalkin settings?

Comment: I can't answer that question, but an easy solution would be to change the slug to a different one for either the post or the page

Comment: @PrasunJajodia ofc, but I'd like to know the cause as one issue might lead to bigger problems later

Comment: this is not a default wordpress behavior in which even if there is some bug posts should have priority over pages, therefor you should lokk in your plugins/themes to check if any of them cause it.... turn off all plugns revert to core theme and then activate one by one.